# Process.Start wait for excel to exit error

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, process.start, waitforexit

Here is my code:

```
Dim sTemplateSharedPath As String = sSharedDrive & ":\Excel Templates\ImportTemplate.xlsx"     
Dim objProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
                    Try
                        objProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
                        objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sTemplateSharedPath
                        objProcess.Start()
                        objProcess.WaitForExit()
                    Catch
                        MessageBox.Show("Could not start process " & sTemplateSharedPath, "Error")
                    End Try
```

Excel opens up the file I requested, but the system crashes at the `objProcess.WaitForExit()` part.The error I get is the following:

> No process is associated with this object.

I want the system to open the template, have the user add his/her data, save and close MS Excel. Once the system detects the process is not running anymore, point to the `sTemplateSharedPath` and import said changes into the system. It's fine if the UI of the app is non responsive while the user is editing the excel document.

I have added the following to the code above before I start the process:

```
objProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false
```

But I then get this error:

> the specified executable is not a valid application for this os platform

I do hope someone will be able to asssist me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to open an excel instance first with the file as parameter?

```
Dim sSharedDrive = "C"
    Dim sTemplateSharedPath As String = "excel.exe"
    Dim FileParam As String = ControlChars.Quote + sSharedDrive + ":\test new\test.xlsx" + ControlChars.Quote
    Dim objProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
    Try
        objProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sTemplateSharedPath
        objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = FileParam
        objProcess.Start()
        objProcess.WaitForExit()
    Catch
        Console.WriteLine("Could not start process " & sTemplateSharedPath, "Error")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Try
```

I dont know if the .xlsx filetype is definied in your os. Can you open the .xlsx manually ?